# Lebesgue measure of a semi-algebraic set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, real-algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a semi-algebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is semi-algebraically homeomorphic to $(0,1)^k$ with $k<n$.

I would require a result stating that $\mathcal{L}^n(A)=0$ where $\mathcal{L}^n$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$. It seems intuitive that this should be true, since $A$ is a k-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e., a set of *lower dimension*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove this is that lower-dimensional manifolds have lower Hausdorff dimension, and a set of lower Hausdorff dimension has Lebesgue measure zero. A semialgebraic set is a finite union of smooth manifolds of various dimensions - see Bochnak-Coste-Roy Theorem 3.3.11 and 3.3.14. You can find the definition and basic properties of Hausdorff dimension in Folland's "Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications" for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am perfectly comfortable with the second part of your argument that states that smooth manifolds of dimension lower than n have Lebesgue measure 0.

However, I have some issues with the first part. Being new to algebraic-geometry, I can somewhat guess that Theorem 3.3.11. could be used to establish that the nonsingular points are a smooth manifold and that with the help of 3.3.14., the same can be shown about the singular points (is that what you had in mind?). However, both results hold for only for algebraic sets and not for semi-algebraic sets.

Comment: @dawo: yes, I was thinking of that decomposition - the singular locus can itself have singular points, so we need $\mathrm{Sing}^{k-1}(X)\setminus \mathrm{Sing}^{k}(X)$ for each $k.$ Semi-algebraic sets fortunately have the same dimension as their algebraic closure - Prop 2.8.2, together with 2.8.9 to relate it to the "$(0,1)^k$" hypothesis.

Comment: I mean $\mathbb R$-Zariski closure

Comment: Great, I can follow your argument and see that it actually answers my original question. In you first post you mentioned that every semi-algebraic set is the union of smooth manifolds - a result that would be of independent interest to me. Following your argument and using the Zariski closure, I can see that the closure can be represented as a union of smooth manifolds but not how the same is true for the set itself. Is there a way to carry this result (union of smooth manifolds) over to the semialgebraic set?

Comment: @dawo: yes, Prop 2.9.10 gives exactly that result